# Can you make vi "advance" the screen when opened?

Tags: vim, scroll, gnu-screen

I often work in vi, suspend vi, run something on the cli, and then fg back into vi to work on the results. For instance, fixing errors that showed up when I ran the cli command.

However, when I fg vi, vi "wipes" the current terminal buffer and I can't see the "last screenful" of terminal output in the scrollback buffer.

Is there some setting in vi (or screen, I use screen) which would help me here?

I have searched google for a long time with no answers. I also realize that there are other workflows that solve this problem, but they aren't perfect (run from inside vi means no shell completion, etc).

Answer (score 8):

If you're using `screen`, then surely it would make sense to do your editing in one window, and your compiles in the other, and then just use the `^A[n]` sequences to flip between your terminal output and code screens?

Comment: I agree.
Another option is to split the screen, see both at once and ^A<Tab> between them.

Comment: For Vim, the :make command is very useful (especially when bound to a key [combination]).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as I said in the original post, my mind is already conditioned for "suspend-run-fg" style of working, and I prefer that for certain scenarios anyway. I am looking for an answer that doesn't involve a different workflow. I also want to know how to control the term anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure whether this will help you or not, but vim tries to restore the screen it found when it was started. I like that behavior and spent quite a bit of time to "repair" a vim installation on a machine where this didn't work.

I had to set the [t_ti](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#'t_ti') and [t_te](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#'t_te') variables. My hunch is that you should unset t_te.

Comment: I think he's using plain vi, not Vim.

Comment: I am using vim. (alias vi=vim, sorry for the mix-up in the question).

This approach sounds really interesting... I looked around the help on these 2 items, but it's a bit out of my wheelhouse... 

I frankly don't know how termcap works etc... what exact commands would you suggest I use?

Comment: This does not work on my AIX. Looking at that web page, I figured out that I can startup with something like `vim -T ansi myfile` and that partially solves the "screen wiped out" problem. Unfortunately, with ansi all the nice coloring and other features are lost, so the cure is worst than the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question in your comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630519/can-you-make-vi-advance-the-screen-when-opened/632482#632482): it seems to actually be the `t_ti` variable. In your `~/.vimrc` add a line that says:

```
set t_ti=""
```

You can try it out first from within `vim` by entering that command at the `:` prompt.

Comment: This has no effect at all on my setup (vim 7.0, AIX 5.3 and $TERM set to aixterm - no way to change anything besides .vimrc). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780483/lines-and-columns-environmental-variables-lost-in-a-script

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but: I use a mac these days, but I used to use NetBSD and Linux at uni.  It always bugged me that programs like `less`, `man`, `vi`, etc. would clear the screen when they exited.  I could switch it off in `less` with the `-X` option, but that wasn't an option (literally) with the others.

I found a config setting in `xterm` that solved the problem for me.  I'm afraid I don't remember the option; it was available through one of the menus and I think through the `-xrw` commandline option.

Obviously this can only be helpful if you use `xterm`.

Comment: On the Mac, I set TERM to dtterm to fix this problem. I think he wants to do the same thing, but with screen, something I don't use.

Comment: which xterm are you talking about? Hardy Hardon's one - i.e. XTerm(229) does not accept `-xrw`. In addition, `less -X` does not solve the problem on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that scrolling the screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> might do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your terminal type to ansi could work:

```
:set term=ansi
```

But I'm sure there are some negative side effects.

Comment: unlikely, if running under 'screen'.  It intercepts all curses-style TTY output, and re-sequences the output.

Comment: If you do what you wrote, it doesn't help at all. If you set it **before** calling vi, e.g. with `vim -T ansi whaterver-the-other-options-are`, then the problem is partially solved (partially in the same sense of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630519/can-you-make-vi-advance-the-screen-when-opened/1783816#1783816 ).  But the cure is worst than the problem, because several functionalities will be cripple (e.g. syntax highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a nice workaround, that I've just started using. Create the following wrapper script for vi (I placed it in my ~/bin/vim-wrapper) and possibly alias it with something like:

```
alias vi='~/bin/vim-wrapper'
```

Content of `vim-wrapper` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780483/lines-and-columns-environmental-variables-lost-in-a-script/1782909#1782909) for details):

```
#!/bin/bash
LINES=$(tput lines)
for i in `seq 1 $LINES`; do
    echo $i
done
vim $@
```

This will solve completely the *screen wiped out* issue. Unfortunately, it does **not** solve the *have to scroll up quite a lot* when you edit a long file in vim. But if you set a large enough buffer in your xterm-like (I use gnome terminal 2.22.1) you'd be ok.