# Define a core.pager in Git using bash variables

Tags: git, bash

I would like to set core.pager in order to manage long lines wrapping text. In order to do it I use this command:

```
$ GIT_PAGER="fold -sw $COLUMNS" git log
```

I tried to set core.pager, but Bash evaluate $COLUMNS too early:

```
$ git config core.pager "fold -sw $COLUMNS"
$ grep pager .git/config
    pager = fold -sw 80
```

If I try to escape $COLUMNS, I get:

```
$ git config core.pager "fold -sw \$COLUMNS"
$ grep pager .git/config
    pager = fold -sw $COLUMNS
$ LC_ALL=en_US git log
fold: option requires an argument -- 'w'
Try 'fold --help' for more information.
```

If I try to use `sh -c` I get:

```
$ git config core.pager 'sh -c fold -sw $COLUMNS'
$ grep pager .git/config
    pager = sh -c fold -sw $COLUMNS
```

..but it doesn't evaluate $COLUMNS correctly (it's static).

How could I get the same behavior of the first command I wrote setting it in core.pager?

Edit: as Nick Bastin has noted `git config core.pager "fold -sw \$COLUMNS"` should work, but probably I've a problem with the child process.

Comment: have you considered using a pager which gets the columns from your terminal emulator and doesnt need to be told explicitly? (like `less`)

Comment: @NevikRehnel less has only `less -r`, that it's good for diffs, but not for logs, where I would get a new line without splitting a word in two parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved setting core.pager like this:

```
$ git config core.pager "fold -sw \$(tput cols)"
```

Thanks to Nick Bastin (which shown the real problem) and this topic: [LINES and COLUMNS environmental variables lost in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780483/lines-and-columns-environmental-variables-lost-in-a-script)

Answer (score 2):

So, this isn't particularly an answer, but I've tested escaping `$COLUMNS` (as you do in your question), and it works fine as long as `COLUMNS` is actually exported in my shell (otherwise it fails as you have above).  Are you sure that `COLUMNS` is defined in your shell, and that git isn't aliased to something that causes you to lose your environment (or aliased to `--no-pager`)?

Edit:  Try a different environment variable.  It turns out that there's a lot of things that want to write the `COLUMNS` variable, and one of them might be screwing you up (I noticed that `fold` would rewrite the variable after I ran it, so it only worked once anyhow).  Try changing `$COLUMNS` to `$FOO` and seeing if that makes a difference.

And, indeed, `grep` itself rewrites the `$COLUMNS` variable on my system to the width of my terminal, so by using `grep` to check the value you may be breaking it:

```
$ export COLUMNS=10
$ echo $COLUMNS
10
$ grep foo
^C
$ echo $COLUMNS
150
```

Comment: `echo $COLUMNS` works and I've no shell alias. I've a very simple git configuration and I'm using Konsole (KDE 4.10.1) actually with Bash 4.2.42.

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli: I was able to do the second thing you did above (escaping it such that .git/config was written properly) and then doing `export COLUMNS=5` would dynamically change the number of columns to 5 (which is amusingly unreadable, of course).  You must have *something* messing with your environment in the child process.

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli: check my edited post - I think your problem is actually `grep` resetting the value of the variable.

Comment: You're right: If I do `export COLUMNS=$COLUMNS` it works, and `grep` is not a good way to check it, but it's not the main problem. Maybe the pager is executed in another bash process that can't see the original $COLUMNS?

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli: the way to test this would be to assign the value you want to a variable that no one else will use, like `export KDFK=$COLUMNS`, and then using `$KDFK` in your config - if that works, then you just have someone screwing with your `COLUMNS` variable.  If it has the same problem, then you have a problem in general with child process environments (which would be very strange).

Comment: With `export KDFK=$COLUMNS` works. It works also with `export COLUMNS=$COLUMNS` (probably this make the variable static).