# Redirecting stderr changes the output of tput but only when capturing the output to a variable?

Tags: shell, terminal, tput

I'm trying to get the width of the current terminal window in a script and use 80 as a fallback in case that isn't possible. I thought that's pretty simple:

```
cols=$( tput cols || echo 80 ) ; echo $cols
# -> 100
```

100 is correct, I made the terminal 100 chars wide. As `cols` is no POSIX conform argument to `tput`, not all systems will support it, thus the fallback. Now let's test the fallback:

```
cols=$( tput colsx || echo 80 ) ; echo $cols
# -> tput: unknown terminfo capability 'colsx'
# -> 80
```

Hmmmm... not so nice. I don't want to see that error. It's printed on `stderr`, so let's just suppress it:

```
cols=$( tput colsx 2>/dev/null || echo 80 ) ; echo $cols
# -> 80
```

Yes, that's much better. So the final code is

```
cols=$( tput cols 2>/dev/null || echo 80 ) ; echo $cols 
# -> 80
```

80? WTF? Why does it run into the fallback now? Let's try this:

```
cols=$( tput cols 2>/dev/null ) ; echo $cols  
# -> 80
```

Ahhhh... redirecting `stderr` changes the output of `tput`? How's that possible? Let's confirm that:

```
tput cols 2>/dev/null
# -> 100
```

Okay, now I'm lost! Can someone please explain me what's going on here?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem, my `BASH_VERSION=4.4.12(1)-release` . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I use `zsh 5.7.1` but switching to `bash` makes no difference, same behavior. So if it is some system oddity that is causing this problem, it seems to affect all my shells.

Comment: Something in you `stty` settings? Good luck.

Comment: And of course hide/comment out any/all `.bash_rc`, `.profile`. (there's a zillion of them). Then turn them back on one at a time to isolate where it is coming form, then if no obvious suspects, comment except 1, and add back 1 at a time will sourcing that file. (Out of ideas for now, maybe more later). Or look at their modification dates, which is newest, and what was changed? Let us know if you find anything. Good luck.

Comment: @Mecki - are you running `tput` on a Linux system? what's your distro, release? I was able to repro on a Debian system.

Comment: @shellter I have emptied all these files for testing purposes (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.zshrc`, there never has been a `.profile` on my system), make no difference.

Comment: @Milag It's actually macOS 10.15.6. Note however that macOS is officially POSIX certified and based on a FreeBSD clone at its core.

Comment: @Mecki - OK, might be worth adding a tag for macOS

Comment: @Milag Not required, as it is not really a macOS issue. Basically you already answered the question, see my answer as well. Other systems may have better fallbacks than macOS and thus report better values but the problem is that when I redirect `stderr` and at the same time capture `stdout`, `tput` has no `tty` any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763978/10304821)

`tput cols` can lead to data from different sources based on these cases:

- one of fd 1,2 is a tty
- both fd 1,2 are not a tty

When running `tput cols` : terminal setting `columns` may be fetched
with an `ioctl()` using fd 1,2 if possible, otherwise get terminfo
capability `cols`.

This session sets 99 for terminal columns,

```
$ stty columns 99; stty -a | grep columns
        speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 99; line = 0;
```

Only fd 1 redirected (to a non-tty):

```
$ tput cols > out; cat out
99
```

Only fd 2 redirected:

```
$ tput cols 2> err; wc -c err
99
0 err
```

Both fd 1,2 redirected:

```
$ tput cols > out 2>&1; cat out
80
```

fd 1 not a tty:

```
$ echo $(tput cols || echo 100)
99
```

fd 1,2 not a tty:

```
$ echo $(tput cols 2> /dev/null || echo 100)
80
```

To show `cols` cabability being fetched when fd 1,2 are redirected,
a terminfo named `tmp` with different `cols` was created and installed, then:

```
$ export TERM=tmp TERMINFO=$HOME/.ti
$ infocmp | grep cols
        colors#8, cols#132, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
```

fd 1,2 not a tty:

```
$ echo $(tput cols 2> /dev/null || echo 100)
132
```

fake cap, tput exits non-zero:

```
$ echo $(tput kol 2> /dev/null || echo 100)
100
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent diagnosis!

Answer (score 1):

**Actually the answer of Milag solves the riddle!** Well, it's a bit complicated and the real answer is a bit hidden within all details given there, so I'm providing a simpler to understand reply here for the interested reader, yet kudos goes to Milag, thus I will accept this answer (also for the reputation).

### In simple words, here is what's going on:

`tput cols` requires a `tty` to get the real terminal width. When I open a terminal window, both `stdout` and `stderr` are `tty`s, thus

```
tput cols
```

prints a correct result. If I now redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`, as in

```
tput cols 2>/dev/null
```

then `stderr` is no longer a `tty`, it is a char file. Yet this is no problem, as `stdout` is still a `tty`.

However, if I capture the output in a variable, as in

```
cols=$( tput cols 2>/dev/null )
```

`stdout` is no `tty` either any longer, it is a pipe to the shell which captures the output of the command. Now `tput` has no `tty` at all anymore and thus cannot obtain the real width any longer, so it uses some fallback and this fallback reports 80 on my system (other systems may have better fallback mechanisms and still report the correct value).

So for my script, I will have to work around this issue a bit:

```
if tput cols >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    cols=$( tput cols )
else
    cols=80
fi
```

The first if checks if `tput` knows the `cols` argument, without producing any visible output at all or capturing anything, I just want to know what the exit code is. If it does support this argument, I capture the output, otherwise I use the fallback directly.