# How could I access shell variable from Perl script?

Tags: shell, perl, environment-variables

In the terminal, I can access variable `$LINES`:

```
$ echo $LINES
39
```

Running Perl script like so:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

 use strict; use warnings;

 my $cmd = q|echo $LINES|;
 my $lines = `$cmd`;

 print "lines: $lines\n";
```

gives output: `lines:`. I tried also  accessing `%ENV`, but it does not contain this particular key.

How could I access shell variable `$LINES` from a Perl script?

Comment: Have you tried `export $LINES` ?

Comment: No, but it should work, cause I tried `LINES=20 my_script.pl` and it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780483/lines-and-columns-environmental-variables-lost-in-a-script

Comment: @w.k : `LINES=20 my_script.pl` is equivalent to `(export LINES=20; my_script.pl)`. You can't see non-exported variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment):

> When a program is invoked it is given an array of strings called the
>   environment. [...] The shell provides several ways to manipulate the
>   environment. On invocation, the shell scans its own environment and
>   creates a parameter for each name found, automatically marking it for
>   export to child processes. **Executed commands** inherit the environment.
>   The **`export`** and `declare  -x` commands allow parameters and functions to
>   be added to and deleted from the environment.

So (assuming a Bash shell) using:

```
export LINES
```

will make the variable `$LINES` available from within a Perl script startet from the Shell (using `$ENV{LINES}` from the Perl script).